# as3 security error #2048

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

I have an app in flash on Facebook. I send a image to my server with this code :

```
var byte_array:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bitmap_data);
var encoded:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(byte_array);
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.png = encoded;

var requestToMySite:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
requestToMySite.url = SITE_URL_HTTPS + 'copy.php';
requestToMySite.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
requestToMySite.data = variables;
var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();  
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onExportComplete);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
loader.load(requestToMySite);
```

The problem is that it works fine for some persons (like me) but for some other persons it doesn't work. I log the problem and I found that they have a SecurityError :

```
[SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048"]
```

I don't understand why It works for some and not for the others. Maybe a strange coincidence : it works for the people who are in france (4 testers) and not outside (a test in Swiss and one in Belgium).

I try to put the following crossdomain.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
   <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
   <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
   <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

and I load it with

```
Security.loadPolicyFile(SITE_URL_HTTP + "crossdomain.xml");
```

(not the https url). But it doesn't change anything.

Any idea ?

Comment: Might be due to the browser Flash player versions?

Comment: If it were a cross domain issue, it should fail for everyone. Are you using a self signed certificate?

Comment: It's not a self signed certificate, it is given with my web hosting but it doesn't seem to be "verified". This is the reason ? URL : https://ssl10.ovh.net/~nivozero/Pix/canvas/

Comment: @crooksy88 : the version of the player is OK, it was the 11.2 or 11.3 on all platform.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem but for me it works on a Mac but not windows computers... We'll keep looking